# Selenium Lightning test failure of not finding "one-app-nav-bar-item-root"

Tags: lightning, lightning-web-components, selenium

We are looking at some Java Selenium/Selenide tests that we have taken over and running those we more or less fail at the first hurdle in this `tagToGo` method:

```
public void goToTab(String value) {
    SelenideElement t = $(byXpath(String.format(
        "//one-app-nav-bar-item-root[.//a[@title='%s']]",
        value
    )));
    t.shouldBe(visible);
    t.click();
}
```

When I Google I find a few references to "one-app-nav-bar-item-root" but don't see such an element in the Lightning page under test looking manually.

Obviously such elements are not part of the platform's API and so can change. Is the element there but I'm just looking for it manually the wrong way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's the Lightning App Navigation Bar for apps that utilize *Standard Navigation* in Navigation Style.

[image]

To search for it, *it helped I had a vague idea it was referring to the navigation bar for apps based on the name*, I utilized the search within Chrome dev tools:

1. Press F12 to open Chrome Developer Tool
2. In `Elements` panel, press CTRL + F
3. In the search box, type in your text (`//one-app-nav-bar-item-root`)

That highlighted/found all the tabs on the bar

[image]

Each tab has a link (for when you click on it) with a title that I presume your method is leveraging. Below is a copied element for Account tab on Sales Console.

```
<one-app-nav-bar-item-root one-appnavbar_appnavbar="" data-id="Account" data-assistive-id="operationId" aria-hidden="false" draggable="true" class="navItem slds-context-bar__item slds-shrink-none slds-is-active" role="listitem">
    <a href="/lightning/o/Account/home" title="Accounts" tabindex="0" draggable="false" aria-current="page" class="slds-context-bar__label-action dndItem">
        <span class="slds-truncate">Accounts</span>
    </a>
...
</one-app-nav-bar-item-root>
```

If it's failing, I would check on the following:

- The String it's passing for the title (that it's correct)
- That the page/app it's on is actually leveraging Standard Navigation and not Console Navigation
- That the tab you're looking for is visible for the user the browser is running as.

Comment: We are using Console navigation. So your answer is spot on. This test code may pre-date the switch to that. Thank-you!